# Issues using Armadillo as a library with CLion & CMake on Windows 10

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, armadillo

I'm trying to use the [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) library inside a CLion project on Windows 10, but when I try to build via `Reload CMake Project` (using the built-in CMake compiler), this error appears after a short while:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2017.2.3/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Armadillo (missing: ARMADILLO_LIBRARY) (found version
  "0.0.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2017.2.3/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:377 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2017.2.3/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindArmadillo.cmake:77 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

I've downloaded the library's content from [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html) and moved it into a folder located at `${PROGRAM FILES}\Armadillo`. To use it in my project, I used the [FindArmadillo module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindArmadillo.html) like this:

```
find_package(Armadillo REQUIRED)    # this is where the error occurs
include_directories(${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
add_executable(MyProject ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(MABE ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES})
```

Is there something I am missing? Do I have to compile the library (or something like that) before I can use it in my project? Or did I maybe mess up the download?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which package did you download? Your link doesn't specify. Almost certainly, you will need to build the Armadillo library. Does `armadillo.lib` exist in `C:\Program Files\armadillo\lib\`?

Comment: I downloaded the `armadillo-8.100.1.tar.xz` package. Neither the lib directory nor the `armadillo.lib` file exist in the armadillo directory, actually. Sorry if this is a silly question, but how do I build the library? Or rather how do I create the .lib file? Do I have to create my own CMakeLists.txt file or do I use the one included in the zip?

Comment: You can use the one included in the archive. Once you've built that, cmake should be able to find the resulting `armadillo.lib` and `armadillo.dll` (if you built a shared library).

Note, if you want better sparce matrix support, you'll also need to open `include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp` and uncomment `#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK` and `#define ARMA_USE_BLAS` to link with the precompiled BLAS and LAPACK libraries.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is still relevant, but for a small project you can save your unzipped files in your project root directory and then add this line to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_include_directories(YOURPROJECTNAME PUBLIC armadillo/include)
```

I am just a beginner and found this to be the easiest solution to add many libraries :)

Hope this helps!